# Using Rand of worksheet function or rnd() of excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a quiz in excel file (version 2007) made with combination of userforms vba and worksheet functions. When the excel file is opened, the first sheet is "quiz" and second hidden sheet is "sheet1". The quiz is working fine but I need to make a small change in the logic. It has a question/answer sheet (sheet1) that is designed in such a way that the first letter of the question is prefixed with the answer. For example here is a sample data in the range A1:A20. Answer to first quesion is "b" hence the question is prefixed with "b".

```
bWho is a cricketer?
Tiger Woods
Sachin Tendulkar
Will Smith
Bill Gates
aWho is a Golfer
Tiger Woods
Sachin Tendulkar
Will Smith
Bill Gates
dWho is an Entrepreneur
Tiger Woods
Sachin Tendulkar
Will Smith
Bill Gates
cWho is an actor
Tiger Woods
Sachin Tendulkar
Will Smith
Bill Gates
```

The questions are randomized and is working properly but when a random question is displayed, the sequence of the answer never changes. Hence, the only thing I need to do is jumble the four answers (in sheet1) whenever the workbook is opened without chaning the logic of prefixing answer to the question's first letter and keeping all other things intact. Please help me how can I achieve this. What kind of code can be written and which section of vba (sheet/module)?

I am showing you example of question 1 how it should be after randomization.

```
cWho is a cricketer?
Will Smith
Bill Gates
Sachin Tendulkar
Tiger Woods
```

Here, the options are jumbled and also the correct answer is updated in the question (prefixed by 'c' which was earlier 'b')
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you could use a *Class Module* or even a *Dictionary*. You can check any of those.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx  Note the value of the answer before shuffling, then find the index of the answer in the shuffled array.

Comment: Thats a good start... will come back soon. thank you

Comment: I am unable to implement this in my question. I also tried finding source on how we can make use of these functions that suits my question to no avail. I am still trying... even if i randomize the four options, how can i get the correct answer sequence (a, b, c, d) to prefix in the question is another tough task. Appreciate any further help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer at [Excel Forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1047574-shuffle-four-answers-of-one-question-with-a-condition-and-loop-it.html) from [Bernie Deitrick](http://www.excelforum.com/members/710873.html)

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim CA As String

    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Step 5
        CA = Cells(r, "A").Offset(Asc(LCase(Left(Cells(r, "A").Value, 1))) - 96, 0).Value
        Cells(r, "A").Offset(1, 1).Resize(4, 1).Formula = "=RAND()"
        With ActiveSheet.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Cells(r, "A").Offset(1, 1).Resize(4, 1), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Cells(r, "A").Offset(1, 0).Resize(4, 2)
            .Header = xlNo
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
        Cells(r, "A").Offset(1, 1).Resize(4, 1).Clear
        CA = Chr(Application.Match(CA, Cells(r, "A").Offset(1, 0).Resize(4, 1), False) + 96)
        Cells(r, "A").Value = CA & Right(Cells(r, "A").Value, Len(Cells(r, "A").Value) - 1)
    Next r
End Sub
```